# Ошибка запроса #1064 при создании триггера MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, openserver

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь создать триггер, но получаю ошибку: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '' на строке 5.

В чём может быть проблема?
Проблема явно не в отсутствии столбца id, в таблице product. Там такой столбец есть и он ключевой.
Не понимаю в чём может быть дело. Все таблицы названы правильно, в таблицах есть нужные столбцы.

Код триггера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_product_image` 
BEFORE DELETE ON `product`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `image_product` WHERE `productId` = OLD.`id`;
END;
```

Также пробовал и такой код:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_product_image 
BEFORE DELETE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM image_product WHERE productId = OLD.id;
END
```

Игрался с запятыми, кавычками, скобками - без толку.

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_product_image
BEFORE DELETE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM image_product WHERE productId = OLD.id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Хотя странно конечно.... Ведь DELIMITER устанавливает разделитель, но разделитель и так установлен в соответствующем поле phpmyadmin. Странно что другие запросы нормально принимает

Comment: внутри запроса и в конце разделитель не может быть одинаковый, делай их разными и все дела)

Comment: благодарю), буду знать